# Conta elemento child de elemento pai na alteração de DOM

Tags: jquery

Uma div recebe novo parágrafo a cada clique, o jQuery confere se houve alteração na DOM, o evento é chamado normalmente porém está retornando a mensagem:

```
UNDEFINED
```

.
A verificação não funciona com **[.size()](https://api.jquery.com/size/)** e **[.lenght](https://api.jquery.com/length/)** de **jQuery v3.3.1**.

HTML:

```
<div class='mensagem-list'></div>
```

E o jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', '.mensagem-list', function() {

        window.alert( $('.p-list').size );

    });
</script>
```

No console a cada clique no botão, o data está ficando assim:

```
<div class='mensagem-list'>
    <p class='p-list'>[mensagem exibida]</p>
    <p class='p-list'>[mensagem exibida]</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria isto que estaria querendo, contar os elementos filhos da div:

```js
$(document.body).on("click", function() {
    $(".mensagem-list").append($("<p>Um novo parágrafo!</p>"));
    var n = $("p").length;
    console.log(n + ' elementos');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='mensagem-list'>
   <p>Um novo parágrafo!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado fera!!!

Comment: Por nada Eliseu.